# Issues connecting to my Node.js and MongoDB backend using a React and axios front end

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, server

I am struggling currently when making a call using Axios to my backend, I currently have a user register page and I want to send the user data to the backend, everything seems to be set up correctly but I get these errors inside of my google chrome.

[image]

Here is the code from my React Register.js that breaks my program and causes this error.

```
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newUser = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      password2: this.state.password2
    };

     axios.post('api/users/register', newUser) //EDIT : Line 35, where the error is
     .then(res => console.log(res.data))
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

The onSubmit is connected to a button at the bottom of the website and all the code there is %100 fine. One issue that might be hurting me here is that my server is on localhost5000 while my front end is running on localhost3000 on my computer. I don't know how to fix this or what to do next, I've looked everywhere and this small issue is incredibyly frustrating.

Any help , pointers or general advice would be greatly appreciated as this seems like an extremely trivial error. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also look into the `create-react-app` docs to setup a proxy. [CRA Proxy Docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development)

I like to setup my proxies in `package.json` (for the react client). I usually add the following, and all my routes start with `api`, to save on typing.

```
// somewhere in package.json
"proxy": {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

If I was still getting a CORS error I would install the npm package `cors` (on the express app) and set that up as a middleware before my route handlers. [Cors Docs](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

```
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

That is the most basic config, but you can specifically whitelist your front end if you want to.

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }))
```

You can also add `cors` to any one route if you want to, in the usual express manner.

```
app.post('/api/user/register', cors(), (req,res) => {
  // route handler
})
```

This is how I setup my apps using CRA and Express for development.  Then when things go to production I don't have to change the api routes on the front end. That is the inherent problem with writing out the whole path ei: 'http://localhost:5000/api/users/register' - that is not going to work when the app goes to production say on Heroku, or wherever, and localhost:5000 is no longer the backend url.  You would have to go back to all api routes and adjust them or insert ternaries for `process.env.NODE_ENV`, which is more work.

In this case all you need on the front end is `axios.post('/api/users/register', newUser)`

The proxy will take care of the rest in development.

Now when you publish site, if you chose to make it one single express app that serves your build statically, you just put the api route handlers above a catch all for serving the index.html. Anyways, this is a little beyond your question, just trying to give you an idea of one approach that will work down the line a little easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for typing all of this out and I will use CORS in another application, but I ended up just using what you recommended in the first part of your response. Thanks for taking your time to write this :).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you run `axios.post('api/users/register', newUser)` it is running simply against `http://localhost`.  You stated that the backend is running at `http://localhost:5000` so you would want to run an absolute address to hit the backend properly.  The code would turn into `axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/register', newUser)` to hit the backend APIs.

Comment: Hey, I copied and pasted that reccomended code in and I got this error in my google Chrome,                                                                                                                                        Failed to load http://localhost:5000/api/users/register: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.                                                                                           Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so first thing is that you're now talking to the back end.  Thats a CORS error coming from the backend which means you don't have CORS configured.  You would need to add a header to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the desired site(s).  If you don't know where the site is then I'd suggest setting it to `*`.  CORS assumes that `localhost:3000` and `localhost:5000` are fundamentally different domains.

Comment: After a quick search (without knowing what framework you're using for the backend) I found https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html for ExpressJS (one of the more common API frameworks) that may be able to help you.

Comment: If you don’t want to do it manually just use ``cors`` npm module. Import in your root file and set it in app like `app.use(cors())``.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "proxy": "http://localhost:5000" in your Client/React Package.json

Comment: Yes I remember I helped you find it on our discord. I am tomcatbuzz.